# SMA() throws .Fortran error

Tags: r, time-series

Is TTR broken? I'm trying to get SMA() to work in R 3.4.3 using this sample code:

```
kings <- scan("http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/misc/kings.dat",skip=3)
kingstimeseries <- ts(kings)
kingstimeseriesSMA3 <- SMA(kingstimeseries,n=3)
plot.ts(kingstimeseriesSMA3)
```

The last line throws

```
Error in .Fortran("runsum", ia = as.double(x[beg:NROW(x)]), lia = as.integer(len),  : 
"runsum" not available for .Fortran() for package "TTR"`
```

Comment: I don't get any error with version 0.23-2 of TTR. You didn't put in code that loaded the package, so could that be the source of the error?

Comment: `install.packages('TTR')` then `library(TTR)`. RStudio wanted to restart because of already-installed packages so I allowed it. Been through the cycle 3 times now: no difference. Maybe there's a package conflict somewhere (I usually only get those with Python!)

Comment: Maybe a version conflict and without further details unlikely to be resolvable. Try Rstudio support with better description of your setup.